# How to get Complete NTFS permissions for Folders and subfolders only from multiple servers

Tags: powershell

I want to write a powershell script which identify number of drives on server and then get NTFS permission from all drives and pull end to end NTFS permissions from folders and there subfolders only not the files on multiple servers.
I tried to write a below script but its only for D drive, unable to trap errors.
As I am very new to powershell, need your help on above.
Note: system drive must be excluded.

```
    $FolderPath = Get-ChildItem  -Path "D:\" -Recurse -Force -Directory
    $Servers = Get-Content .\Servers.txt
    $Output = @() 

    ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
    {
    Write-Host "Getting NTFS permission from " $Server
ForEach ($Folder in ($FolderPath)) { 
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName 
    ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access) { 
$Properties = [ordered]@{'Server'=$Server;'Folder Name'=$Folder.FullName;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited} 
$Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties 
    } 
}
}
$Output | export-csv -path .\NTFSPerm.csv
```

Comment: With Windows you have to adhere to both NTFS and Group Policy.  So if you are an Admin you need to have no local admin rights, but across the network as well.  To access across the network as admin you use a dollar sign instead of the colon in the path.  So try : -Path "D$\".

Comment: I do not have admin access. I am designing script and then server admin will execute it on server.

Comment: How do you expect to test without the permission to run the script?

Comment: I am designing script and giving them for testing. I have just login access rights to device and there I am testing it for any error.

Comment: Add the try/catch exception handle to capture errors.